# Pycharm expects ndarray out of numpy.mean instead of a float

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, type-hinting

Title is pretty self explanatory.

Minimal reproducible code:

```
import numpy
mean_sex: float = numpy.mean([1, 2, 3])
print(mean_sex)
print(type(mean_sex))
```

Output is:

```
001 | 2.0
002 | <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

But PyCharm does this:
[image]

I'm using:
PyCharm 2022.2 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-222.3345.131, built on July 27, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.3+7-b469.32 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2030M
Cores: 16
Non-Bundled Plugins:
com.chesterccw.excelreader (2022.2.1)

Comment: yeah, `np.mean` doesn't return a `float`, in this case, it returns a `numpy.float64` object, actually, instead of a `numpy.ndarray`. You can just choose to ignore the linting, or if it bothers you, use `mean_sex = float(numpy.mean([1,2,3])`

Comment: Typing it as `numpy.float64` doesn't work either though. Not sure if you suggested i could type hint it as a `numpy.float64`

Comment: I did not. I suggested you simply use `mean_sex = float(numpy.mean([1,2,3]))`

Comment: Fairs, not sure what you meant with the `numpy.float64` object, sorry if that was supposed to be obvious, i'm quite a beginner.

Comment: I'm saying that the `np.mean()` call (in this case) returns a `numpy.float64` object, not a `float` object. which is why your output for `print(type(mean_sex))` was `<class 'numpy.float64'>`

Comment: Ohh ok, yes thanks! But I think even an object of class `numpy.float64` can be type hinted as `float` because `numpy.float64` inherits from `float`, right? (EDIT: I'm trying to look at the source code to determine if that's true but I don't understand anything about it)

Comment: No, no it does not. This is what I was trying to communicate, they are two unrelated types

Comment: Ohhh, my bad then! How do you know they're not related (so that I don't ask stupid questions next time :D)?

Comment: see `print(issubclss(float, np.float64))`

Comment: `print(issubclass(np.float64, float))` returns `True` though

Comment: Ah, it must be registered as a virtual subclass I imagine. But maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.mean()` can return several types (the return type is `Any`) and what is actually returned depends on the arguments to the function.

This is fairly typical in Python, since it is a dynamically typed language - there are no hard restrictions on what type a function returns and hinting can only get you so far.

In this case, what type is returned depends on the value of parameters like `axis`, which could cause the function to return a `numpy.ndarray` instead of a `numpy.float64`. Since you made it clear that you want `mean_sex` to explicitly contain a `float`, that causes the type hint you shared.

The solution is to make sure that the value coming out of `numpy.mean()` is actually a `float`, for example by passing it to `float()`:

```
mean_sex: float = float(numpy.mean([1, 2, 3]))
```

The question here is "why bother?" You could just as easily do:

```
mean_sex = numpy.mean([1, 2, 3])
```

Is there a reason you want to specify the type for `mean_sex`?

Comment: I wanted to use mypyc later so I think I have to type-hint everything.

Comment: That's not a bad reason, but if that's the aim, you'll need to be very careful about passing around types, and need to be aware of what types function you use produce, and whether you need to explicitly convert types when they don't match - or catch the error when they don't.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks!

Comment: "numpy.mean() can return several types (the return type is Any)" That isn't what `Any` means.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - no, it's not. `Any` essentially means the return type is unspecified, as it could return "any" type, though that is of course not literally true either. The sentence continues though and I don't think the way it's phrased is confusing, although there's always room for pedantry.

Comment: `Any` essentially means "don't type check". Your sentence implies to me that `Any` means "can return several types". I believe the most recent versions of `numpy` have actual type annotations for it

Comment: If it is type hinted as Any why does it expect a ndarray though?

Comment: I can't see the `->` sign in the source code: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.23.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L3313-L3433 which is a bit odd?

Comment: It's in a stub file, see here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/54c52f13713f3d21795926ca4dbb27e16fada171/numpy/__init__.pyi#L1263

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows it tries to infer the return type and correctly identifies that it *can* return an `ndarray`, which would cause trouble for your code (because you added the type hint). So, you'll either need to deal with the possible return types, or force the type through calling a conversion function (if you're certain it would never actually return an `ndarray` in your code).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `Any` does not mean "don't type check", it means ["unconstrained type"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any) and is compatible with any type, as documentation indicates. Unconstrained, as in any type could be returned (obviously still constrained by the actual logic of the function).

Comment: @Grismar the thing I don't understand is how can it identify it as an `ndarray` if the return type is set to be `Any`?

Comment: There's [more on type hinting in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html) on the JetBrains website but it infers the type from the code. You've probably seen this in action when you wrote your own code. Try writing a simple function without type hints that returns a string and then assiging its return value to a variable type hinted to be an `int`. PCcharm will show a warning, even though you provided no type hints, inferring from the code that the return value must be a string.

Comment: In this case, the return type can be any one of a number of types (i.e. `Any`), so when you try to force it into a type-hinted variable, PyCharm tries to infer if that would cause issues. After all, if you have a function that always returns a float, even if it is type-hinted as `Any`, there is no real issue. PyCharm correctly identifies that the function technically could return an `ndarray` and thus you get a warning. In your case, it wouldn't because of runtime values, but that's something the compiler cannot infer - there's a difference between runtime and compile-time checking.

Comment: @Grismar "PyCharm correctly identifies that the function technically could return an ndarray and thus you get a warning" why does it not identify that the function can return an ndarray OR a float?

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows the way the `numpy` package is written doesn't make that clear to PyCharm - this is not an issue with PyCharm but with the way numpy is coded and documented. Some information can be inferred from the code and some directly interpreted from documentation, but it's not guaranteed to be correct, unless the developers maintain and test their code hints. PyCharm tries its best to warn you of possible problem, and in this case it is correct, just not 100% accurate.